# I have 3 Big Jpanels can't set them in JFrame using any layout manager

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I have 3 big jpanels and I want to put them in 3 rows and 1 columns but turns out only one of them will be appear on the form and I want them to be fixed not resizing when I resize the JFrame.

here is what I've done:

1-create a JPanel(somehow)

2-pass the created JPs to the JF

3-in JF create a gridlayoumanager and config it like following

```
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3, 1, 30, 20);
        Container content = this.getContentPane(); 
        content.setLayout(grid);
```

4-add the JPs to the JF

but still no luck!

Comment: That's not a big issue. Show your code here.

Comment: seems JRE 1.7 has some issues in debug mode , now its works in release mode